# How to implement voice recognition with my own (tiny) dictionary?

Tags: android, dictionary, voice-recognition

I would like to implement offline voice recognition in my app. But I want it for two purposes:

1. For a small set of commands (play, stop, previous, next and a couple of others);
2. For a list of a few hundred bird names.

To implement (1), it seems to me a bad idea (slower and resource consuming) to use the full voice recognition force of android. In my mind, it would be easier to tell my app to only interpret a few words. That is, to use my own dictionary, telling my app to "use only these 10 words".

To implement (2) is similar to (1), but with a few hundred instead of 10.

Does this makes sense, and if so is there an *easy* way to implement it? Is it worth it?

Thanks!

L.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your app using CMUSphinx on Android. CMUSphinx tutorial is here:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial

The language models to recognize limited set of words are described here

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm

You can use keyword spotting mode to recognize few commands.

Pocketsphinx on Android is described here:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

The demonstration includes the way to switch recognition modes from 10 words to few hundred words as you intend.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll give it a try. Thanks!